# How to hide overlapping pixels using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have two images of similar dimensions as such:

[image]

[image]

Since the outer circle should have close to overlapping pixels, I would like to have a resultant image that has the inner circle from image A and the square from image B. I thought inverting image A and then calling `PIL.Image.composite(imageA, imageB, mask)` would do something but it just gave me a combination of imageA and imageB.

Is there a way to do what I want using Pillow or perhaps using numpy somehow to make white the pixels that are similar between both images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for an XOR between the two images.

I'll work up to it slowly in case you don't do many logical expression evaluations, so starting with **OR**, you will get white pixels out as a result where the **either** image A **OR** image B has white pixels. Then with an **AND**, you will get white pixels out where both image A **AND** image B are white. Finally, with an **XOR**, you will get white pixels out where either image A or image B but **exclusively one or the other** but not both have white pixels.

In code, that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

# Load up the two images, discarding any alpha channel
im1 = Image.open('im1.png').convert('1')
im2 = Image.open('im2.png').convert('1')

# XOR the images together
result = ImageChops.logical_xor(im1,im2)
result = ImageChops.invert(result)

# Save the result
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]